# push() can not display string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am doing a password strength check typescript code by using Angular. Everything works fine except for "push" can not display the messages. If I use "=", then works fine, such as "this.message='Hello'". But I could not figure out when using "this.messages.push('xxxx')",it does not show anything. Anyone please help ?

Here is part of my ts code:

```
 export class PasswordComponent implements OnInit {
      password = '';
      message = 'Your message goes here';
      messages: string[] = ["Hello"];

      constructor() { }

      checkPassword(password: string) {
        let pw:string = this.password;
        this.c_length();
        this.c_numberCnt();
      }

      c_length(): void {
        if ( this.password.length <= 1) {
          this.messages.push('The length of the password is too short');
        }
      }

      c_numberCnt(): void {
        let test;
        let regex = /\d/g;
        test=regex.test(this.password);
        if (!test) {
          this.messages.push('At lease one number');
        }
      }

      c_metaCnt(): void {
        let tt:boolean;
          tt = !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(this.password);
          if (!tt) {
            this.messages.push('At lease one special character');
          }
      }

      c_upperCnt(): void {
       if (this.password.toLowerCase()==this.password) {
          this.messages.push('At lease one Uppercase');
       }
      }

      c_lowerCnt(): void {
        if (this.password.toUpperCase()==this.password) {
          this.messages.push('At lease one lowercase');
       }
      }

  resetPassword() {
    this.password = '';
  }

}
```

Comment: how you are displaying it on the component? because its an array

Comment: Sounds like the OP is using `{message}` in the UI, but populating an array of messages. Two different properties. Here _"this.message='Hello'"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because **`messages`** is an array, so you need to use ngFor to iterate over colleciton, so in your template use it as follows

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let messageObj of messages">
      {{ messageObj }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect!!Thank you so much!

Comment: Got it. I did not notice this before. Sorry.